# Magento Upgrade There was no Home CMS page configured or found. after upgrade

Tags: magento, content-management-system, upgrade

Recently upgraded Magento website from 1.7 to 1.9.  Everything seemed to go smooth with a few easy to fix errors.  But something that has me stumped is error "There was no Home CMS page configured or found."

Everything in `CMS > Pages` is enabled
Stores are there and configured (dual domain setup .ca and .com)
`Configuration > General > Web` is the same config as before and I even adjusted these settings to try and find a fix to no avail.

Current config is...

Default Config:

```
Default Web URL : CMS
CMS Home Page : Home - CDN
Default No-Route URL : cms/index/noRoute
CMS No Route Page : Shopper No Route Page
CMS No Cookies Page : Enable Cookies
Show Breadcrums for CMS Pages : Yes
```

Site 1 Default Pages:

```
Default Web URL : CMS Use Default Checked
CMS Home Page : Home - CDN Use Default Checked
Default No-Route URL : cms/index/noRoute Use Default Checked
CMS No Route Page : Shopper No Route Page Use Default Checked
CMS No Cookies Page : Enable Cookies Use Default Checked
Show Breadcrums for CMS Pages : Yes Use Default Checked
```

Site 2 Default Pages:

```
Default Web URL : CMS Use Default UnChecked
CMS Home Page : Home - USA Use Default UnChecked
Default No-Route URL : cms/index/noRoute Use Default UnChecked
CMS No Route Page : Shopper No Route Page Use Default UnChecked
CMS No Cookies Page : Enable Cookies Use Default UnChecked
Show Breadcrums for CMS Pages : Yes Use Default UnChecked
```

Main website

```
Default Web URL : CMS Use Default Checked
CMS Home Page : Home - CDN Use Default Checked
Default No-Route URL : cms/index/noRoute Use Default Checked
CMS No Route Page : Shopper No Route Page Use Default Checked
CMS No Cookies Page : Enable Cookies Use Default Checked
Show Breadcrums for CMS Pages : Yes Use Default Checked
```

I'm guessing there is either something wrong here or .htaccess files... although they didn't change at all with the update.  Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  I've read plenty of threads talking about issues with CMS pages not being enabled or CMS home page not being selected.  From what I can tell that is not the case here.

Thank you in advance for your time.